# Understanding execution of WebAPIs with setTimeout & DOM Api

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout, event-loop

I have been working with JS for about a year now and I'm still learning it. My question is at the end.

In the first example:

```
console.log('Start');

setTimeout(()=> console.log('inside callback'), 0); 

console.log('End');
```

outputs

```
Start
End
inside callback
```

I understand that even though the timeout is `0`, it still had to go to browser WebApi (setTimeout api) and immediately pushed into callback queue waiting for the main thread to be free (which is currently executing console.log('End')). Once the thread is free callback is executed & "inside callback" is printed.

Following this approach, **I tried to experiment it with another WebAPI i.e DOM API.**

This time, Instead of setTimeout, I used document.querySelectorAll()

```
console.log('Start');

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('img'))

console.log('End');
```

Outputs

```
Start 
NodeList(4) [img.bar-sm.-avatar.js-avatar-me, img.bar-sm.avatar.s-avatar--image, img, img]
End
```

**This time we see DOM API output before END is printed.**

I know the output but I want to understand the flow behind it.

**Why it didn't follow the pattern like setTimeout?**

**Why didn't the DOM output came after "End" if it was processed on separate thread.**

Did it follow the flow below:

**document.querySelectorAll -> webAPI -> callback queue -> main thread**

Does DOM API have to go though callback queue and **wait for main thread to be empty**. **If so? how come we got consoles in the right order this time unlike with setTimeout**

I'm still learning and would appreciate explanation a lot. Please point anything if I misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) pushes the callback, after `timeout` ms, into a [queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) that will be processed first-in-first-out. `.querySelectorAll()` is executed immediately.

Comment: Yes, the best explanation I'm at is because querySelectorAll is synchronous while setTimeout is asynchronous. Right?

Comment: `setTimeout()` on its own is also synchronous. But it triggers an asynchronous action, namely adding the supplied callback to a queue that is processed later in time.

Comment: "setTimeout() on its own is also synchronous" I'm not sure what you mean by it. developer.mozilla mentions "setTimeout() is an asynchronous function, meaning that the timer function will not pause execution of other functions in the functions stack."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: Sorry, I might have been a bit to nit-picky here... `/* code/statement A */; setTimeout(); /* code/statement B */;` will always be executed in the same order: `A` -> `setTimeout()` -> `B`, because that part is synchronous. But the callback, the scheduled part of the `setTimeout()` call, is executed later in time -> asynchronous. So saying `setTimeout()` is asynchronous is (almost) correct because the relevant part of it (the callback) is actually asynchronous.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `document.querySelectorAll` is a synchronous method where as the `setTimeout` is asynchronous.

JS scripts are being executed in the same environment that the DOM lives in, so it is not asynchronous. Asynchronous events are events that generally get sent to another environment (later to be handled by the event loop)

This is part of the concurrency model based on an event loop, which is actually responsible for executing the code, collecting and processing event. The setTimeout function is called with 2 arguments: a message to add to the callback queue, and a time value (optional; defaults to 0). The time value represents the (minimum) delay after which the message will actually be pushed into the queue. If there is no other message in the queue, and the stack is empty, the message is processed right after the delay. However, if there are messages, the setTimeout message will have to wait for other messages to be processed and For this reason, the second argument indicates a minimum time (not a guaranteed time). So, the message 'end' will be written to the console before the message in the callback 'inside callback' gets processed, because the delay is the minimum time required for the runtime to process the request (not a guaranteed time).

`document.querySelectorAll` is part of scripts that are being executed in the same environment that the DOM lives in, so it is not asynchronous and will be executed immediately.

DOM manipulation is synchronous. having said that, the browser's re-rendering  process of the page in response to a DOM update is asynchronous. This can give the illusion of an asynchronous DOM update.

More about the JavaScript **event loop** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: So does this mean that all browser DOM APIs are synchronous?

Comment: I will add the answer to your question because it's a good question

Comment: please take a look now @WaleedAhmad